# How to add a bower package from a local directory in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bower, bower-install

In explorer, I can see a `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` files at the root of the project directory. I can also see that you can manage packages within Visual Studio.

I'm guessing Visual Studio is hiding those bower files on purpose. I can't find settings to add another source in `Tools>Options`. Am I supposed to only use official bower packages?  Is there a way to use a bower package from a local directory within Visual Studio's interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the `Dependencies` in Solution Explorer and select `Open bower.json`.

In the `bower.json` file, I can add a new dependency like `"example":"C:/path/to/my/bower/folder/"`